# Merging methods that get Lists from type <? extends Number>

Tags: java, generics

I wrote 4 methods that calculate the average of a List.
Can I merge these methods in any way ? I'd like to have a single method that is like

```
private double getAverage(@NotNull List<? extends Number> list) {
    //magic code from stackoverflow
}
```

Currently this is what I did:

```
    private double getAverageDouble(@NotNull List<Double> list) {
    double result = 0;

    for (Double value : list) {
        result += value / (double)list.size();
    }
    return result;
}



private double getAverageFloat(@NotNull List<Float> list) {
    double result = 0;

    for (Float value : list) {
        result += value / (double)list.size();
    }
    return result;
}




private double getAverageInteger(@NotNull List<Integer> list) {
    double result = 0;

    for (Integer value : list) {
        result += value / (double)list.size();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Same for Long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue()) method of `Number`.

```
public static double average(List<? extends Number> list) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (Number number : list) {
    sum += number.doubleValue();
  }
  return sum / list.size();
}
```

You could also simplify this with [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

```
public static double average(List<? extends Number> list) {
  return list.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).average().orElse(0.0);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, was about to make an answer similar to this, with the addition of a [Try it online](https://tio.run/##bZBBT8MgGIbv/RVfdmpdpFWn080t2cHb9LJkF@OBtayhUmjgYzpNf3tlUBObeYHA83zw5q3ogV5WxXvX8bpRGqFyF8QiF@RiHuWCGgPPlMvvCKCxO8FzMEjRbQfFC6gdijeouSxf34AmJw1gzQ0@vth6x/QShDvAAiT7gJXW9OjhMk7mXj1RQosivsqSOaQpcImsZHoIJ@Qm0EK5DGwIr9eBCSXLIZmS@4d9gHuhKEYeb44GWU2URdK44ChkPHr6bFiOrJjBHckm09tRH@8/d5WjpWLm6GhcMlwdmKYli0@/Jn6sjc7KCrnhj37WUQKhvF41tnatZSQLQfZKQxx0kGGbDcbAT4wXPSXhmS0Vlv123fpVM7RaejsNVRn@1Ttt1HbdDw) link, mainly the reason why you were faster. ;) +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

`Number` gives `doubleValue()`, and you can use that in the calculation:

```
private <T extends Number> double getAverage(@NotNull List<T> list) {
    double result = 0;

    for (Number value : list) {
        result += value.doubleValue() / list.size();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And that method can be called with `List<Integer>`, `List<Float>`, `List<Double>`, etc.

But note that the implementation can be as simple as (java8+):

```
return list.stream()
    .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
    .average()
    .orElse(0)
```